# Blender's world environment sky looks flat

Tags: world

Has anyone addressed the Blender environment sky horizon? It occurs to me so many landscapes are childish refrigerator art (mine certainly included) because Blender's sky horizon is at zero degrees off the X,Y axis no matter what the camera's Z location.

I would say there needs to be a 'degrees off tangent.' If looking directly straight out is along a tangent plane, then the horizon of a sphere would fall some degrees away from that regardless of distance or diameter of the sphere. The higher you were, the greater the degrees. This might allow Blender artists to submit better landscapes?

Comment: If you want the horizon to act like a sphere, then you can use a sphere, right?

Comment: I want it to act like a horizon. The environment isn't a Mesh object so the distance is not a factor to contend with. The sky textures and Dynamic world also include controls a Sphere's material don't include without imagining the same solutions.

Comment: You want to mimic the look of the **earth**s horizon, with you say looks flat right now, right? Why don't you use a partial sphere, since the earth actually resembles a sphere? (I don't think I understad your question yet.)

Comment: The higher you are means you can see farther around a sphere you're on which makes the horizon appear lower. Nothing in Blender's sky textures I'm aware of allows for this. The Sky textures provide a ton of useful lighting however. But this means modeling a camera on a mountain means having to curl up the surrounding landscape to essentially hide the flaw of the horizon. Conversely, you can't make the Salt Flats at sea level in Blender either! Meshes can't "reach" the horizon properly. (This probably isn't on everyone's mind!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust the coordinates of the Environment texture to manipulate the 'centreline' of the environment. This can be achieved with the following nodes :

[image: adjust environment]

Adjust the Mapping node to skew the coordinates in a specific direction. The Normalize node ensures the result is still a valid Normal for the environment texture.

Obviously there are limitations to this since the environment is effectively projected onto an infinite sphere - adjusting too far will noticeably reduce one half of the environment into an ever decreasing circle while stretching out the opposite side.

Comment: Tested; doesn't repeat at the top Z pole. The mapping answer dawned on me after describing it in terms of Z:0 to someone. Thank you! Additionally, Dynamic Sky addon needs Mapping Node added en route to sky colors node.